# Get mqtt message header in node.js server with mosquitto broker

Tags: node.js, mqtt, mosquitto

How to get header agent or device/browser details in mqtt message with mosquitto broker. My mqtt code sample:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://127.0.0.1:1883',{
   username: 'xxxx',
   password: 'xxxx'
});
client.on('connect', function (err,done) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log("Connected...")
        client.subscribe('test');
    }
})
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // want to get the header details here.
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get anything other than the message payload and topic from a MQTT message because no other information is included in the message format. This is by design, in Pub/Sub messaging the only thing that matters in the topic and the payload, not who sent it.

The `on('message',function(){})` callback can take a 3rd parameter which is the raw mqtt-packet object. You can see full list of data available in the doc [here](https://github.com/mqttjs/mqtt-packet#publish). But the only extra information is about duplicate status, qos and if the message is retained.

```
client.on('message',function(topic, message, mqtt-packet) {
...
});
```

If you need more information you need to manually include it in the message payload published by the client yourself.